# Nested form input for join table attributes in a has_many through association, parameter is unpermitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have a PurchaseOrder model and an Item model joined in a Quantity model via has_many through.

purchase_order.rb

```
class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, :through => :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

*item.rb*

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :purchase_orders, through: :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

*quantity.rb*

```
class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :purchase_order
  belongs_to :item
```

The Quantity join model has an extra attribute called 'amount':

```
Quantity id: nil, amount: nil, purchase_order_id: nil, item_id: nil
```

In the new PurchaseOrder form, I want to set the amount in the Quantity join table for each new item that is created.  I believe I have it almost working, but I get an error when saving the new PurchaseOrder that says `Unpermitted parameters: quantity`

Here is the code in my new PurchaseOrder form:

```
<%= f.fields_for @q do |quantity| %> 
    <%= quantity.number_field :amount %><br>
    <% end %>
```

I'm using rails 4, so in my PurchaseOrders controller, in the `permit` function I have:

```
def purchase_order_params
  params.require(:purchase_order).permit(:Date, :purchase_order_number, 
    :description, :quantity => [], :quantities_attributes => [], :amount, 
    :item_ids => [], :item_attributes => [], :supplier_ids => [])
end
```

This is the params hash that gets submitted in the form but still gives the error:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DMZ6lROwRr11S3XLc2eXcb2In+G4weMZCJwhF0Bt8kQ=",
    "purchase_order"=>{"Date(1i)"=>"2013", "Date(2i)"=>"12", "Date(3i)"=>"29",
    "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "quantity"=>{"amount"=>"98"}, "supplier_ids"=>["", "4"],
    "description"=>"", "amount"=>""}, "id"=>"170"}
```

Why is the quantity parameter still unpermitted? Why will it not save the :amount in the Quantity join table when I submit the form?  Or do I have this setup all wrong?

**UPDATE**
Here is the full PurchaseOrder controller code:
https://github.com/andrewcockerham/inventory/blob/master/app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb

And here's the full sever error: (with `quantity => []`)

```
Processing by PurchaseOrdersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"DMZ6lROwRr11S3XLc2eXcb2In+G4weMZCJwhF0Bt8kQ=", "purchase_order"=>   {"Date(1i)"=>"2014", "Date(2i)"=>"1", "Date(3i)"=>"1", "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "quantity"=>{"amount"=>"2345"}, "supplier_ids"=>["", "5"], "description"=>"2345", "amount"=>"2345"}, "id"=>"197"}
  PurchaseOrder Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "purchase_orders".* FROM "purchase_orders" WHERE "purchase_orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "197"]]
Unpermitted parameters: quantity
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "quantities" ON "items"."id" = "quantities"."item_id" WHERE "quantities"."purchase_order_id" = ?  [["purchase_order_id", 197]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "quantities" ("created_at", "item_id", "purchase_order_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00], ["item_id", 9], ["purchase_order_id", 197], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00]]
  Supplier Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" WHERE "suppliers"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Supplier Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "suppliers"."id" = "orders"."supplier_id" WHERE "orders"."purchase_order_id" = ?  [["purchase_order_id", 197]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "purchase_order_id", "supplier_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00], ["purchase_order_id", 197], ["supplier_id", 5], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00]]
  PurchaseOrder Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "purchase_orders" WHERE ("purchase_orders"."purchase_order_number" = '20140101-04' AND "purchase_orders"."id" != 197) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "purchase_orders" SET "description" = ?, "amount" = ?, "Date" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "purchase_orders"."id" = 197  [["description", "2345"], ["amount", #<BigDecimal:7ff184e1e4c0,'0.2345E4',9(18)>], ["Date", Wed, 01 Jan 2014], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
    `Redirected to http://localhost:3001/purchase_orders/197`
Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)


Started GET "/purchase_orders/197" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-01 15:00:40 -0600
Processing by PurchaseOrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"197"}
  PurchaseOrder Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "purchase_orders".* FROM "purchase_orders" WHERE "purchase_orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "197"]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.where(...).all instead. (called from show at /Users/Andrew/code/RailsCode/TVA2/TVAInventory/app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:23)
  Quantity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "quantities".* FROM "quantities" WHERE "quantities"."purchase_order_id" = 197
  Supplier Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "suppliers"."id" = "orders"."supplier_id" WHERE "orders"."purchase_order_id" = ?  [["purchase_order_id", 197]]
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "quantities" ON "items"."id" = "quantities"."item_id" WHERE "quantities"."purchase_order_id" = ?  [["purchase_order_id", 197]]
  Rendered purchase_orders/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

And with `quantity => [:amount]`

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: quantity):
  app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:79:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:78:in `update'
```

The entire code can be viewed in the github repo.

Comment: In your whitelist you have `:quantity => [], :quantities_attributes => [], :amount,`. Is the `:amount` a field in a table other than `Quantity`? Have you tried just removing `:quantity => []` from your whitelist to see what happens? What are the columns in the other two models? Can you show the entire web server log when you submit the form and it hits the error?

Comment: I'm thinking either `:quantity => [:amount]` or `quantities_attributes => [:amount]` might be what you are looking for? Try those also and let me know.

Comment: I tried both of those, and I get the unknown attribute error from the `purchaseorder#update` action. I've updated the post to include the controller code and the full error code

Comment: I've reloaded this page in two different browsers and see no new error code or controller code.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was still typing :)

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Final Answer ** edited 1/1/2014
First we cut down on confusion by changing the "quantity.amount" field in the DB to "quantity.count" with a migration:  **Historical note, :count is a bad choice since COUNT is a SQL function**

```
class RenameAmountInQauntities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :quantities, :amount, :count
  end
end
```

run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to change the table. Now you have to go into your views, etc. where you were using "amount" in reference to Quantity and change it to "count" I think the only places I really ran into it were in the `app/views/quantities...` files. Now onto your controller

I edited your `purchase_order#new` here:

```
  def new
  ...

  @purchase_order.purchase_order_number = @next_po_number
  # @q = @purchase_order.quantity.build ## something like this to create the Quantity record?
  @purchase_order.save
  @purchase_order.quantities.build
  # @q = Quantity.find_by_purchase_order_id(@purchase_order.id)
  @items = Item.all.order("part_number")
  @suppliers = Supplier.all.order("name")
  ...
```

Notice that instead of `@q` I'm using the `.build` method to make the relation that will go into the nested form. Then we make sure the form is able to accept the fields in

```
`...view/purchase_orders/_form.html.erb`:  
  <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |quantities| %>
      <%=  quantities.label :count %>
      <%=  quantities.text_field :count %><br>
  <% end %>
```

Your params look like this, note that now `:count` and `:id` are nested attributes for `:quantities_attributes`:

```
params.require(:purchase_order).permit(:Date, :purchase_order_number, :description, :amount, :count,
                                          :quantities_attributes => [:count, :id], :item_ids => [],
                                          :item_attributes => [], :supplier_ids => [])
```

Our form now returns:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xilSf3CQuXoY0mnjE+jF9APXetuNv3MgMHh4JbmFzk0=", "purchase_order"=>{"Date(1i)"=>"2014", "Date(2i)"=>"1", "Date(3i)"=>"2", "item_ids"=>["", "1"], "quantities_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"count"=>"22"}}, "supplier_ids"=>["", "1"], "description"=>"whoa", "amount"=>"44"}}
```

and we get a proper save. Everything seems to work great, except for some reason my `.build` method inserts a record into Quantities with the current `purchase_order :id` as it's foreign key, then instead of updating that record, it inserts another. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

```
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "quantities" ("created_at", "item_id", "purchase_order_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 02 Jan 2014 06:18:01 UTC +00:00], ["item_id", 1], ["purchase_order_id", 68], ["updated_at", Thu, 02 Jan 2014 06:18:01 UTC +00:00]]
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "quantities" ("count", "created_at", "purchase_order_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["count", "22"], ["created_at", Thu, 02 Jan 2014 06:18:01 UTC +00:00], ["purchase_order_id", 68], ["updated_at", Thu, 02 Jan 2014 06:18:01 UTC +00:00]]
```

I'm throwing in the towel, I've answered pretty much every question you've brought up. I hope that you'll accept this answer and move on.

Sadly the more I poked at this application, the more things I found that bewildered me. In your `new` action for the PurchaseOrder controller you save the new purchase order. I can see WHY it's being done, to be able to construct the PO number out of the date and an incremented integer. But this causes you to have those horrible `Create` and `Delete` buttons at the bottom of your `/purchase_order/new` form. You should just have Submit and Clear buttons. You probably shouldn't be saving records before they are actually created in the `#create` action. You probably shouldn't be creating the PO number the way you do. And you should definitely be moving all of that business logic into methods in your models. If this is a real production app you are using, or plan to use, I would refactor most of it from the ground up after subscribing to https://www.codeschool.com/paths/ruby#rails-best-practices and watching their "Rails Best Practices" and "Rails 4 Patterns". No offense intended, I'm still learning myself, but there are some real train wrecks in this app. I would also recommend using the [Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for nested forms. I saw this as a good exercise in learning nested forms and sharpening my Params Hash skills, and we're just sitting in front of the TV watching the first couple seasons of Downton Abbey, so I'm glad I was able to solve most of the mystery. Good luck!

**End of final edit**
The rest below are left as an historical reference for anyone wanting to follow the train of though used to get here.

---

Ok, several things seem to be wrong here. Here is my testing in the Rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.0.0-p353 :001 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new("purchase_order"=>{"Date(1i)"=>"2013", "Date(2i)"=>"12", "Date(3i)"=>"29", "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "quantity"=>{"amount"=>"98"}, "supplier_ids"=>["", "4"], "description"=>"", "amount"=>""}, "id"=>"170")

=> {"purchase_order"=>{"Date(1i)"=>"2013", "Date(2i)"=>"12", "Date(3i)"=>"29", "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "quantity"=>{"amount"=>"98"}, "supplier_ids"=>["", "4"], "description"=>"", "amount"=>""}, "id"=>"170"} 

2.0.0-p353 :002 > params.require(:purchase_order).permit(:Date, :purchase_order_number, :description, :quantity => [], :quantities_attributes => [], :amount, :item_ids => [], :item_attributes => [], :supplier_ids => [])
 SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
 ...ties_attributes => [], :amount, :item_ids => [], :item_attri...
 ...                               ^
from /Users/uw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/uw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/uw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

So right off the bat I think you need to move any non-hash type declarations in the .permit section to before the ones that are using the hash syntax. I've seen this before, and am still unclear on why, but I just do it by default now. So we move `:amount` towards the front and we get:

```
2.0.0-p353 :003 > params.require(:purchase_order).permit(:Date, :purchase_order_number, :description, :amount, :quantity => [], :quantities_attributes => [], :item_ids => [], :item_attributes => [], :supplier_ids => [])
Unpermitted parameters: quantity
  => {"Date(1i)"=>"2013", "Date(2i)"=>"12", "Date(3i)"=>"29", "description"=>"", "amount"=>"", "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "supplier_ids"=>["", "4"]}
```

So Rails is doing it's job and blocking what you gave it for `:quantity` because it's expecting a single value. So change it to `:quantity => [:amount]` and we see:

```
2.0.0-p353 :004 > params.require(:purchase_order).permit(:Date, :purchase_order_number, :description, :amount, :quantity => [:amount], :quantities_attributes => [], :item_ids => [], :item_attributes => [], :supplier_ids => [])
 => {"Date(1i)"=>"2013", "Date(2i)"=>"12", "Date(3i)"=>"29", "description"=>"", "amount"=>"", "quantity"=>{"amount"=>"98"}, "item_ids"=>["", "9"], "supplier_ids"=>["", "4"]}
```

Strong Parameters has now passed on your hash data happily. That solves your stated problem. Let me know if you actually get what you are looking for when you hit the controller action on submit now that the hash is getting through the whitelist. I don't see your controller code so I can't promise it will.

** EDIT **

With the updates you posted we can determine:

```
:quantity => []
```

will always give you an `Unpermitted parameters: quantity` , because your form is returning a hash. Either change your form to return a scalar value, or use `

```
:quantity => [:amount]
```

But I don't think you want `:quantity => [:amount]` since the controller update action doesn't like it. You can see when you use `:quantity => []` you actually get a result, the DB does some updating and then the web server returns a `#show` action. So, is the DB updating correctly when you use the `:quantity => []` version? You have a very complex issue well beyond your "Parameter upermitted" error. You will need to determine several things:

1. You need to determine if the DB update that completes in your first example is doing what you want. The one thing that jumps out at me is the last commit: 
    `UPDATE "purchase_orders" SET "description" = ?, "amount" = ?, "Date" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "purchase_orders"."id" = 197 [["description", "2345"], ["amount", #], ["Date", Wed, 01 Jan 2014], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00]] (1.1ms) commit transaction`

   Does this seem right? i.e. `"amount" = ?` and `["amount", #]` This is no doubt tied to the fact that you have "amount" in two places in your params hash (so your form is returning two different values) one as `"quantity"=>{"amount"=>"98"}` and the other as `"amount"=>""`
2. You need look at your form that is getting rendered by the browser. This will show you how the parameters are being nested. You have a nested form that returns nested attributes. Which attributes are failing to be updated in the DB? Is this because your form is wrong or because your `.permit` action is set up wrong? Your DB call on update is rather complex, possibly you need to restructure the form to give you certain parameters nested in the parameters hash.
3. Also note, your "amount" is supposed to be in the "Qauntities" table but here is your insert:
   `INSERT INTO "quantities" ("created_at", "item_id", "purchase_order_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [["created_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00], ["item_id", 9], ["purchase_order_id", 197], ["updated_at", Wed, 01 Jan 2014 21:00:40 UTC +00:00]]`

   Note you are not setting an amount. Also you have "amount" in Purchase Orders and in Quantities. That is quite confusing in itself. Do they represent two different pieces of data?

As this goes beyond a simple Parameters Hash problem I would close out this question and start a new one based on "Accepts nested attributes not working in nested form and join table" or something along those lines. Also read this before crafting your next question, I think it relates to what you have going on:  [Rails nested form with has_many :through, how to edit attributes of join model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model?rq=1)

Nested forms can drive me mad. I would check out this: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon and the Stackoverflow question that led me to it: [Rails forms for has_many through association with additional attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352977/rails-forms-for-has-many-through-association-with-additional-attributes?rq=1)

I cloned your project from Github and everything works except that you are never setting the `quantity.amount` for a new purchase_order. It is because your form is not passing in the correct information for the controller to be able to update the Quantities table. One thing I did to make life much easier is to rename the `amount` column in the Quantities table to `count`. You already have a column in the PurchaseOrders table called `amount` that represents a dollar amount. Save yourself and any future maintainers the headaches and do this to yours so that they have distinct names that represent what they are. You will also have to change any references to :amount where it pertains to the Quantities controller.

I expanded the views for the Quantities controller so that `app/views/quantities/_form` shows the quantity's purchase order and item name. I can call `localhost:3000/quantities` and then edit one of the quantity entries in the DB, giving it a `:count`. THAT is what is failing in your form and your create/update actions.

Comment: I updated my post to show the `update` function.  I updated my `.permit` function to match yours identically, and then I get this error: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: quantity):
  app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:79:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/purchase_orders_controller.rb:78:in `update'

Comment: I don't see any change on reloading the page, are you editing it? I've solved your params problem. What you are seeing now is a completely different problem related to your controller code and probably your form code. I suggest you create a new question based on the new problem. You'll need to post your entire controller and form code, plus the output of your web server, not just the error. The important thing here is to remember that I can't see any of that unless you post it. The web server log can have tons of useful data to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: This is probably not a huge error, but it would be FAR easier to solve seeing all of your code. Is this on Github? Can you upload it to Github?

Comment: Yes, just updated the post with the link. Thanks so much for your help!  But now getting 'unknown attribute' error....so are you sayings its related to a different problem?

Comment: I changed the `:amount` column in the `Quantities` table to be `:count` like you suggested. But of course it doesn't change the unpermitted parameter error.I agree that I can go to `localhost:3000/quantities` and edit the `:count` column there no problem. But you're right, the question is, how can I set the new PurchaseOrder form so that I can input the now `:count` column (`quantity.count`) from there? I can make a new question,but this question is not really resolved because I still get the unpermitted parameter error.I will try the other questions you linked to.Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I actually figured it out and am typing up an answer, but first have to track down why I'm now creating two Quantity records on each PO save.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your patience and hard work Beartech! You have been extremely helpful. I ran into this problem of creating two Quantities before, and I think the reason is because 1 is created on `purchase_order.save` and the other is created on `purchase_order.quantities.build`. I agree, I will try to find a way to do this without saving the purchase_order before creating it. And thanks for the general advice about the app...I know the code is a mess. I'm still learning, and apparently the app I'm trying to make is super complicated :) I'm going to start from scratch. Thanks again!!

Comment: @andrewcockerham Did you get anywhere with the order of save and build in the controller? If so can you push the new controller on your Git? I am having the same type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `quantity` parameter is a hash, but you've only permitted it to be an array. There is no way, to my knowledge, to specify that a hash is allowed.

Comment: Yes, I thought there might be some issue with that.  So then how can I set the :amount column of the Quantity join model in the new PurchaseOrder form?

Comment: Sorry, I've got to run and not sure when I'll be able to get back to this.

Comment: `:quantity => [:amount]` will work just fine for returning a hash of `{:amount => "some amount"}`. The place you really run into problems is when you want to pass a hash and you don't know what the keys will be beforehand. Then you have to do some trickery with `.tap` as shown near the end of this example: http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html